# safe characters for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am abstracting a tweet from a users profile using json. I am then inserting it in a database. I need to know how to safely put the characters into a mySql database and then convert them back to the normal tweet again.

For example the word "doesn't" is going in the database as "doesnâ€™t"

ALSO, If the Tweet happens to have quotes in it, then they are gone as well. 
There must be a way to preserve these and get them back again.

How can I safely add this and how can I convert it back again?

I have tried this SQL line:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tweetCheck (Timestamp, Tweet) VALUES ('$Timestamp', '$Tweet')");
```

Here is the encoding: [image]

Comment: Using prepared statements? So long as your database has the correct encoding type you'll be fine. Show what you've tried.

Comment: Added a pic in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use real_escape_string**

```
$tweet_to_be_stored_in_db = $mysqli->real_escape_string($tweet);
```

OR using PDO

```
PDO::quote
```

This answer worked:

```
$Tweet = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Tweet);
```

Comment: What about calling it again? Do I need to convert it back?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau not needed

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in

Comment: @PapaDeBeau which PHP version are you using ?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.3.24

Comment: Its coming from a jSon script: $obj = json_decode($jsonString);
$Tweet =  $obj->tweets[$id]->text;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48042/discussion-between-codingant-and-papa-de-beau)

Comment: This seemed to work: $Tweet = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Tweet);

Comment: @PapaDeBeau ok ! Great

Comment: @PapaDeBeau Please accept the answer if it solved your issue, so that the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with the "safety" of the characters, and everything to do with character encoding.

Looks like the tweet is in UTF-8, but your database (or possibly the database connection) is not.

Of course, this is assuming you're already taking proper sanitation methods... a hazardous assumption, certainly!

Comment: Added a pic in my question.

Comment: Is this what you mean? $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Could not connect.");